# Not getting current user location

Tags: iphone

in .h file

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,MKReverseGeocoderDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{

}
```

in .m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
     MKReverseGeocoder *geoCoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
     geoCoder.delegate = self;
     [geoCoder start];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
     NSLog(@"locationManager:%@ didFailWithError:%@", manager, error);
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
     MKPlacemark * myPlacemark = placemark;

     NSString *kABPersonAddressCityKey;
     NSString *city = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressCityKey];

     lblAddress.text = city;

     NSLog(@"city detail is:--> %@",city);
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder:%@ didFailWithError:%@", geocoder, error);
}
```

This is the code which I have done to get the current location of user & print it in the label.

But the `CLLocationManager` delegate method (which are written above) is not called & I am not able to get the current address.

Please help me out.

Where I am doing mistake...? guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of autoreleasing the `CLLocationManager` instance, assign it to an ivar in your class.  Then release it in `-dealloc` as usual (or in one of the delegate methods if you don't need it any longer).

I suspect your location manager is getting deallocated on the next turn of the run loop before having an opportunity to fire off its delegate methods.

Comment: What is the error?  (Btw, I think you're leaking your reverse geocoder.)

Comment: reverseGeocoder:<MKReverseGeocoder: 0x226c80> didFailWithError:Error Domain=PBRequesterErrorDomain Code=6001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (PBRequesterErrorDomain error 6001.)"

Comment: Seems fine to me - did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031038/reversegeocoder-fail-error-in-mapkit ?

Comment: Your `newLocation.coordinate` contains the lat/long.  Are you sure your current location is geocodable?  If you are on iOS 5 or newer have you considered `CLGeocoder`?  (Oh, is this in the simulator by any chance?)

Comment: Got me... sounds like an actual geocoding error.  I'd suggest following the suggestions in the linked question and/or open a new question for this issue.  (Please accept my answer for this question since it sounds like it fixed the immediate problem you were asking about.)

Comment: As I said, it sounds like an actual geocoding error, not an error in your code.  Sounds like rate limits might cause it.  Otherwise, maybe try in a different location?  If you can't get it to work, post a new question on the geocoding problem and you might attract people who have more experience with such issues.

Comment: (I have lots of experience with maps and location services, but not so much with geocoding; sorry.  If you post a question tagged with "geocoding" you can probably get someone who knows more about that aspect of your problem.)

Comment: Just post a new one, like you posted this (the "Ask Question" button up top).

Comment: On StackOverflow it's best to have separate questions for separate issues.  This one was for your location-finding problem.  Now you have a new one related to geocoding, so make it a new question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13833/discussion-between-jignesh-fadadu-and-conrad-shultz)

Answer (score 1):

In your method `viewDidLoad`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;     // add this line

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And you are done!!!

Comment: You most definitely do *not* need to display location on a map in order to get location; you don't even need an `MKMapView` instance at all!  And in any event the property is `showsUserLocation` not `showUserLocation`.